# Conditional Inheritance neglects changed condition in workspace in python

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes that have a similar structure but different functionality. I want a third class to be able to inherit from either of them based on my needs. Let's say I have an objects module and I have defined classes A, B, and C in the module. This is how I do the conditional inheritance after a syntax I found on the internet:

```
cond = True

class C(A if cond else B):

    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
```

in which A and B are other classes in the module objects. Now when I import objects and class C from the objects module into a jupyter notebook and change the `cond`:

```
objects.cond = False
my_class = C()
```

No effect seems to be taking place as I check the name of the parent class. Meaning that after changing the condition, I expect the class C to inherit from B, but instead it inherits from class A as if `cond` still evaluates to `True`. I have tried with not importing the class from the module and just import the objects module and instantiate my class with `my_class = objects.C()` but still the new condition will not be issued.

Now it is not difficult in my case just to change the condition manually inside the module whenever I need to, but I was wondering what all of this says about python's syntax. Am I doing something wrong or is this because of some sort of command priority between the module and class level in python? Or could the syntax be possibly wrong?

N.B. I have not written a complete class C, other stuff is being done in class C and some of them would change based on which parent is inherited. The code is to serve as a dummy but IMO sufficient example.

Comment: Have you tried with just classes A & B in the importing module and setting cond and defining C locally?  I  think this is required for your conditional inheritance since code is executed on import i.e. "keywords such as class and def are not declarations. Instead, they are real live statements which are executed".

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, I was just wondering what was going on at a deeper level in python. I think it would not be harmful to provide an answer that thoroughly explains what you just commented.

Comment: @P.basimfar--posted an answer.  Let me know if this helps the clarificaition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

Python import works as follows:

- It executes the code in the module
- Symbols created by executing the module code are placed in the module symbol table (including class C)
- import only loads a module once (i.e. the module is cache) for a process.  Thus, subsequent imports of the same module has no effect.
- Consequently, the definition for class C is placed in the module symbol table on the first import.  Changing cond after the import thus has no affect on the definition.
- Use reload to force the reload of a module (i.e. not using the cache version).

Sharging global variables across modules

- A suggested approach is the place the global shared variables in a config module

Considering the above the following code works.

**Code**

*config.py* (contains globals to share across modules)

```
cond = True
```

*test_abc.py* (contains the definition of classes a, b, c)

```
import config

class A(): 
    def __init__(self, x): 
        self.x = x
      
    def getX(self): 
        return f"A {self.x}"
    
class B(): 
    def __init__(self, x): 
        self.x = x
      
    def getX(self): 
        return f"B {self.x}"   
  
# inherits from A or B
class C(A if config.cond else B):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)
```

*main.py* (main program)

```
from importlib import reload             # Allows reloading of modules
import config                            # place variables we want to share across modules

# Test with cond = True
config.cond = True                       # Use True in condition for inheritance                         
import test_abc                            # Use import first time, can reload on subsequent calls
ca = test_abc.C(1)
print("First call: ", ca.getX())         # Test that we obtain A object

# Test with cond = False
config.cond = False
reload(test_abc)                          # reload module

ca = test_abc.C(1)
print("Second call:", ca.getX())        # Test that we obtained B object
```

**Output**

```
First call:  A 1
Second call: B 1
```